# Cookie does not get added in .NET 5 Cookie Authentication Scheme

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, authorization, .net-5

I am learning Authentication and Authorization in .net 5. This is what I have so far:

"Login.cshtml":

```html
@model LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}

<h1>Login</h1>

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group align-content-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(user => user.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "email" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(user => user.PasswordHash, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "password", @type = "password" })
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

"ActionsController":

```cs
[Route("/Login")]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("/Login")]
public IActionResult Login([Bind] LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (model.Email == "user@fmail.com" && model.PasswordHash == "1234")
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Bar F Har"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "user@fmail.com"),
            new Claim("Age", "25")
        };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

        HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);

        return Redirect("/"); // redirects to the page
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound(); //works!!
    }
}
```

---

I inspected the debugger. The only problem seems to be that the cookie is not being added:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "Test.Cookie";
    options.LoginPath = "/Login";
});
```

---

`app.Authentication();` and `app.Authorization();` have been placed correcty in that order after `app.UseRouting();`

---

What am I missing?

Comment: You're meant to `await` async methods...

Comment: This is the error I get in that case: `InvalidOperationException: SignInAsync when principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false is not allowed when AuthenticationOptions.RequireAuthenticatedSignIn is true.`

Comment: @Llama, and I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66452220/11930602). Does not work for me :(

Comment: You're getting that error even if you don't `await` it - it's just that you don't see it. Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54722600/identity-signin-passwordsignin-returns-success-but-user-identity-isauthentic)?

Comment: Um.. Yes, but that post is using Identity, I am not

Comment: Nobody said you have to use the identity system. From your comment, it sounds like you're advertse to using `services.AddAuthentication();`. In that case: why are you even using `SignInAsync`?

Comment: So, if I have AddAuthentication, I don't need SignInAsync?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, if you want `SignInAsync` to work, then you need to have `AddAuthentication`... `AddAuthentication` isn't part of identity.

Comment: Wait, you are literally contradicting the earlier comment [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999347/cookie-does-not-get-added-in-net-5-cookie-authentication-scheme#comment123740010_69999347) comment says I don't need SignInAsync; but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999347/cookie-does-not-get-added-in-net-5-cookie-authentication-scheme#comment123740030_69999347) one says I do? I am confused

Comment: No I'm not. I said if you don't want to use the authentication middlware, what is the benefit you expect from using SignInAsync? It won't make your user authenticated with your application because you don't have the authentication middleware. You see how nonsensical that is?

Comment: Yes; but app.UseAuthentication adds the middleware, right?

Comment: `services.AddAuthentication()` registers the services it needs, and `app.UseAuthentication()` actually sets it up so that it's active, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Then I have both

Comment: Then why on Earth did you say "Yes, but that post is using Identity, I am not" rather than "I already have that?" ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this was pretty simple:
Changing `HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);` to `HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal);` did the trick.